# How to select an option in a dropdown based on a value on the model using thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I would like to select an option in a dropdown using a value in my Model (org.springframework.ui.Model), I know how to do it with `th:object` and `th:field` but what if I don't have an object and only a key/value in the model?
I'm using spring boot 2 and thymeleaf 3.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm understanding the question correctly you want to display values on your drop-down options first ( so that you could select one of them further) based on the selected Model.?
And May I know how you're selecting the Model , is it from UI ?

For example :--

You have selected a value in a HTML option( Values from your Model ), and based on that Selected Value you want to display the values further on another HTML-option which you can select further.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need th:object and/or th:field to dynamically select a option. Just add your options to the model and use the th:selected attribute.

```
<select ...>
  <option  ...
    th:each="op : ${myOptions}"
    th:value="${op.myValueMember}"
    th:text="${op.myTextMember}"
    th:selected="${op.myTextMember == 'Chimichanga'}"
  >
  </option>
</select>
```